# Generating sudoku puzzles with less than 25 clues

Tags: sudoku

I've written a solver/generator that gives me puzzles of varying difficulty of 25 or more clues relatively fast. However, if I try to generate a sudoku with less than that number of clues, from 17 to 24, it takes forever.

Here's how my algorithm looks like:

1. Generate 100,000 filled boards
2. Take the next board from the list
3. Remove clues on a single pass
4. Try solving it
5. Repeat 3 to 4 for at least 5 times with different set of clues
6. If no solution could be found, start over from step 2

Possible issues I see:

1. I see some puzzle creators mention they remove clues in several passes and try a solution on every single pass. I've tried a similar approach with my solver and I don't really see a change there.
2. I've only implemented 17 strategies, Finned fishes and fishes up to n=4 (Jellyfish) are there. I'm missing more powerful techniques such as coloring. Can this also be an issue?

The generation of 100,000 filled boards on the fly is not an issue. I measure the time and of course it takes some time until the generator creates them all, but it really has no impact on the problem I'm trying to solve.

Any ideas how could I improve my solver? From your experience, where should I try to spend the most time to improve it? is it on the solver itself, is it on board generation or is it on clues deletion process?

Comment: Why generate 100.000? Why not just generate one randomly, at the start of every loop.

Comment: I want the solver to check as many puzzles as it can, as fast as it can. Generating fulfilled boards and even clues patterns seem like a problem that can be resolved separately without affecting the main algorithm. I'll give it a try though and see how it goes.